# Hela live cell confocal laser scanning - reccommendations for good fluorophore that will show good movement

Tags: cell-culture, fluorescent-microscopy, cell

I've been doing a lot of live cell imaging lately mostly using hela cells expressing some EYFP based chimeric proteins. I'm building a video library for an art student here at the university who is going to create an exposition using the videos. I need a lot of content to make this sucessful and rather than requiring much scientific merit these videos need to be "busy" and look good. I'm looking for suggestions as to any dyes or fluorophores, drug treatments or conditions someone has worked with that will show significant movement/change of/in the cell, change in intracellular localization....doesn't matter it just needs to be a significant alteration for the cell.

I'm still really optimizing the system with the CO₂ etc.. and the longest aquisition i have taken is about 8 hours - after that either the cells are dead or the focal drift becomes too much of a problem. I am hoping to see some division once I can get the system recording long enough. Until then was looking for some suggestions as to other possibilities.

The various dyes I have been using include:  hoechst, dapi, mito-tracker, draq5, er-red, rox-red. also eyfp/tubulin, eyfy/mito, eyfp/golgi, draq5. These dyes aren't cheap and I'm only one i know doing this so I'm checking here.

Comment: I am not really sure, what you are asking for. You are looking for a fluophore that is nicely visible in confocal microscopy? Or do you want to tag a protein, which moves a lot? Or do you want to see whole moving cells?

Comment: Thank you Chris, I added a lot of needed info to the original question.

Comment: You could think about tagging proteins, which are imported and exported from the nucleus.

Answer (score 2):

[MitoSOX](http://www.lifetechnologies.com/order/catalog/product/M36008?CID=search-M36008) looks pretty cool. I've never used it myself, but I'm sure you could see some cool mitochondrial dynamics going on. Its a bit pricey though, but all dyes are going to be.

Even at only 8 hours you should probably be able to see a few divisions, which would be cool with hoechst.